# Custom site collection + 404

Tags: 404

I used this guide build clean visual studio project: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sambetts/archive/2013/10/17/creating-a-clean-visual-studio-solution-from-a-sharepoint-2013-site-template.aspx

Everything went well when I used blank site template. But when I tried to use team site, 
I can not get it to work. I can deploy solution and I can create site collection but, when I try browse site it gives me 404.

Here is Master Pages Elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="MasterPages" Url="_catalogs/masterpage" RootWebOnly="FALSE" Path="Files \_catalogs\masterpage" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <File Url="EMaster.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE" Level="Published" ReplaceContent="TRUE" Path="EMaster.master">
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Here is Pages Elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Module Name="HomePages" Url="" RootWebOnly="FALSE" Path="Files" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<File Url="Home.aspx" Level="Published" Path="Home.aspx" />
</Module>
</Elements>
```

Also, I change page name Home.aspx, what was not in guide.
Can anyone help me? What is problem here?

Comment: Please add more details for investigation: could you post ULS logs errors when you create and firstly enter your sitecollection

Comment: I think the issue is with the master page not able to load. Can you check if your master page is available under _catalogs\masterpage folder through browser or SPD after the deployment?

Comment: Another thing to check is whether or not approval is turned on on the masterpage library. I've seen that cause issues. Not sure what the default is for a team site.

Comment: Problem was Home.aspx. I don't know why it doesn't work if I rename default.aspx to Home.aspx. If I change it back to default.aspx it works fine. I tried configure Elements.xml but it didn't help me.